# Ruby array - how can I make values persist over nil values

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm working with an array of midi pitches, which looks like this...

```
pitches = [
  60, nil, nil, nil, 67, nil, nil, nil, 
  nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, 
  nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, 
  nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil
]
```

In this case, the pitch is still 60 on indexes 1, 2 and 3.

Following index 4, the pitch is still 67.

How can I write a method to identify the previous non-nil value?

The only way I can currently think to do it looks a little clumsy:

```
def pitch_at_step(pitches,step)
  if pitches.any?
    x = pitches[step]
    until x != nil
      index -= 1
      x = pitches[step]        
    end 
    x
  else
    nil
  end 
end
```

The expected output is in the format:

```
pitch_at_step(pitches, 0) # 60
pitch_at_step(pitches, 2) # 60
pitch_at_step(pitches, 4) # 67
pitch_at_step(pitches, 8) # 67
```

Is this the best solution? is there a tidier and/or more efficient way?

Comment: Can you give also the output? So that we don't need to run your code.

Comment: It should be the most recent non-nil value, so 0: 60, 1: 60, 2: 60, 3: 60, 4: 67, 5: 67, 6: 67 etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If array is not big you can use something like this:

```
pitches[0..index].compact.last
```

This seems tidier, but it's not as good as your for big arrays of data

Comment: This looks good, as it happens the app is based on short loops which the user can modify. I would be surprised if they ever exceed 64 steps.

Answer (score 3):

```
pitches.slice_before(&:itself).flat_map{|a| a.fill(a.first)}
# => [60, 60, 60, 60, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 
#     67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67]
```

Comment: Kernel#itself only available from 2.2.0 onwards. (This answer certainly taught me a thing or two...)

Comment: Slightly less elegant but for earlier rubies it looks as if you can use `slice_before{|x| x != nil}`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple way to construct the converted array:

```
last = pitches.first
pitches[1..-1].map { |i| curr = i || last; last = curr; curr }
              .unshift(pitches.first)
  #=> [60, 60, 60, 60, 67,... 67]
```

The OP did not say whether the first element of `pitches` is always non-nil.  Suppose:

```
pitches = [nil, nil, 61, nil, nil, 60, nil]
```

The above method would return:

```
[nil, nil, 61, 61, 61, 60, 60]
```

which is what we would want. Some of the other answers stumble when `pitches[step] = nil` and `pitches[i] = nil` for all `i < step` (`step` being the index of the given element of `pitches`).

Comment: Good point, the right answer will be that the array is read as a repeating pattern. The pitch will remain as the last value it was set to. HOWEVER - there is a bit mask defining when to start sounding the tone, the first member of which will be on the same point as the first defined pitch, so there is no need to worry about nils at the start of the array

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to have large arrays which are mostly `nil`, why not use a hash instead, store only the non-nil values ? And you look on the keys. (here, an unoptimized version)

```
pitches = {0 => 60, 4 => 67}

def find(idx)
  lower = pitches.keys.select { |i| i <= idx}
  return pitches[lower.sort.last]
end
```

If performance is an issue, you can keep track of the sorted keys.

Comment: This is a good idea, and may also solve an issue I'm likely to run in to with data transfer via JSON. It does however mean I will have to implement this solution in javascript on the client.

Answer (score 1):

To get one value:

```
 value = index.downto(0){|i| pitches[i] and break pitches[i] }
```

To calculate all the values:

```
 values = (y = nil) || pitches.map{|x| x ? y = x : y }
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be achieved with [`Enumerable#chunk`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk):

```
tmp = nil
pitches.chunk {|el| tmp = el unless el.nil?; tmp }.
  map {|val, ar| [val] * ar.size }.flatten
# => [60, 60, 60, 60, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 
#     67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good way to do it in Ruby:

```
pitches[0..index].reverse_each.find{|x|x}
```